# Optional parameters: Multiple constructors cause errors

Tags: java

Since in Java optional parameters are not possible, I tried to create 2 constructors.

```java
public class Tts {
    public Context context;
    private final MediaPlayer _mediaPlayer;
    private final CopyBarVisualizer _barTop;
    private final CopyBarVisualizer _barBottom;

    public Tts(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public Tts(Context context, MediaPlayer _mediaPlayer, BarVisualizer _barTop, BarVisualizer _barBottom) {
        this.context = context;
        this._mediaPlayer = _mediaPlayer;
        this._barTop = (CopyBarVisualizer) _barTop;
        this._barBottom = (CopyBarVisualizer) _barBottom;
    }
}
```

Now my problems are the private properties. There I get the error

> Variable '_mediaPlayer' might not have been initialized

In another method, I want to check if the properties are set. But how can I avoid these errors?

Comment: The variables are final so you must set them in the constructor. If you want them to be optional, remove the `final` keyword and check for null values. (Also prefixing with `_` isn't done in Java.)

Comment: If I call `Tts(someContext)`, what is the value of `_mediaPlayer`? You haven't given it a value in that constructor.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas yes, removing `final` worked for me. Thank you!

Comment: I will define the other properties in another method. That's why they are not defined in the constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to solve the error problem, you can fix it with the code below; however, when the constructor initializes final fields, you can't change them, so probably it's better to remove the final keyword.

```
public class Tts {
    public Context context;
    private final MediaPlayer _mediaPlayer; 
    private final CopyBarVisualizer _barTop; 
    private final CopyBarVisualizer _barBottom; 

    public Tts(Context context) {
        this(context, null, null, null); // to solve the error problem
    }

    public Tts(Context context, MediaPlayer _mediaPlayer, BarVisualizer _barTop, BarVisualizer _barBottom) {
        this.context = context;
        this._mediaPlayer = _mediaPlayer;
        this._barTop = (CopyBarVisualizer) _barTop;
        this._barBottom = (CopyBarVisualizer) _barBottom;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### To resolve the error, you can:

#### Delete *final* keyword in attributes

```java
public class Tts {
    public Context context;
    private MediaPlayer _mediaPlayer;
    private CopyBarVisualizer _barTop;
    private CopyBarVisualizer _barBottom;

    public Tts(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public Tts(Context context, MediaPlayer _mediaPlayer, BarVisualizer _barTop, BarVisualizer _barBottom) {
        this.context = context;
        this._mediaPlayer = _mediaPlayer;
        this._barTop = (CopyBarVisualizer) _barTop;
        this._barBottom = (CopyBarVisualizer) _barBottom;
    }
}
```

#### Give *null* value to your *final* attributes

```java
public class Tts {
    public Context context;
    private final MediaPlayer _mediaPlayer; 
    private final CopyBarVisualizer _barTop; 
    private final CopyBarVisualizer _barBottom; 

    public Tts(Context context) {
        this(context, null, null, null); // to solve the error problem
    }

    public Tts(Context context, MediaPlayer _mediaPlayer, BarVisualizer _barTop, BarVisualizer _barBottom) {
        this.context = context;
        this._mediaPlayer = _mediaPlayer;
        this._barTop = (CopyBarVisualizer) _barTop;
        this._barBottom = (CopyBarVisualizer) _barBottom;
    }
}
```

*[This code is from @Khahani](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70559203/15186569)*

---

### For optional attributes in your class you can use *Builder pattern* :

```java
public class TtsBuilder{
    public Context context;
    private MediaPlayer _mediaPlayer = null;
    private BarVisualizer _barTop = null;
    private BarVisualizer _barBottom = null;

    public TtsBuilder(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public TtsBuilder withMediaPlayer(MediaPlayer _mediaPlayer) {
        this._mediaPlayer = _mediaPlayer;
        return this;
    }

    public TtsBuilder withBarTop(BarVisualizer _barTop) {
        this._barTop = _barTop;
        return this;
    }

    public TtsBuilder withBarBottom(BarVisualizer _barBottom) {
        this._barBottom = _barBottom;
        return this;
    }

    public Tts build() {
        return new Tts(context, _mediaPlayer, _barTop, _barBottom);
    }
}
```

#### Example :

```java
public static void main(String[] args){
    Tts ttsMedia = new Tts(aContext).withMediaPlayer(aMediaPlayer).build();
    Tts ttsBarTopBottom = new Tts(aContext)
            .withBarTop(aBarTop)
            .withBarBottom(aBarBottom)
            .build();
}
```

---

### Note

The naming convention in Java recommends:

> Variable names should not start with underscore _ or dollar sign $ characters, even though both are allowed.

For more details you can check [Oracle documentation](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html).

Comment: Explicitly assigning null isn't necessary -- if you declare an object type variable but don't assign it, it will be null by default.